# How to get key in hash value in puppet

Tags: configuration, puppet

I don't know if it is even possible.
I have a manifest like this:

```
$some_external_value = 'pew_pew'
$dict = {
    ensure => $ensure,
    configuration => {
         "random_name-${some_external_value}" => {
            command => 'python script.py config/random_name-${some_external_value}.cfg',
         },
         "some_other_name-${some_external_value}" => {
            command => 'python script.py config/some_other_name-${some_external_value}.cfg',
         },
         "without-external" => {
            command => "python script.py config/without-external.cfg",
            user => 'cluster',
         },
      }
}
notice ($dict["configuration"]["some_other_name-${some_external_value}"]["command"])
```

I get

```
notice: Scope(Class[main]): python script.py config/some_other_name-pew_pew.cfg
```

Is there some trick to write key name just once and after that just refer it?

```
"some_other_name-${some_external_value}" => {
     command => 'python script.py config/${wild_magic_variable_pasting_key_here}.cfg',
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can likely get there either with a [custom parser function](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/custom_functions.html).

```
$orig_dict = {
  ...
  configuration => {
     "random_name-${some_external_value}" => {
        command => 'python script.py config/__KEY__.cfg',
     },
  ...
}

$dict = keysubst($orig_dict)
```

...where the ruby function does the work of replacing the `__KEY__` token with the respective key value recursively.